# Embeded tool in web app to design form and connect to application data

Tags: java, forms, jsp

what kind of tool or approach would you suggest for the following scenario:

JSP/Servlets web application

need to design forms and connect this forms to actual data from the db (for example select form fields from a specific list of fields) while the web app is running

save and use the above forms to store data to DB

any approach or tool indication is welcome

The basic idea would be:
h have the possibility to design a form from the application and then have user use it to store data, for example the administrator logs in, creates/designs a from with certain fields (connecting those fields to actual data from the db), stores that form, publishes it to be used by users. The user logs in, selects the just-published form, inputs data, saves to db

EDIT: i am receiving downvotes, while it is ok, as i am mainly looking for advice, please do state what makes this question so unbearably bad that you need to down-vote, without maybe giving a hint to what i should change. It seems to me that the question relates to a specific problem i am facing, while trying to build a solution.

EDIT 2:  i need to design the form while the application is running, and use the form again from the app. It has nothing to do with coding forms in a JSP page or connection to databases or things like that.

Comment: This question can not really answered as it very general like "how to make a JSP application with a database backend". What are the points which are not clear to you? Is it e.g. the database connection or frontend techniques with JSPs and Servlets?

Comment: none of what you mentioned, it is the fact that i need to design the form while the application is running, and use the form again from the app. It has nothing to do with coding forms in a JSP page.

Comment: I do not understand the part "design the form while the application is running", what do you mean exactly with it?

Comment: the idea would be to have the possibility to design a form from the application and then have user use it to store data, for example the administrator logs in, creates/designs a from with certain fields (connecting those fields to actual data from the db), stores that form, publishes it to be used by users. The user logs in, selects the just-published form, inputs data, saves to db.